# Iterate through 2d list and select range from co-ordinates in Python

Tags: python, list, coordinates

```
gridsize=5

m= [[0 for i in range(gridsize)] for i in range(gridsize)]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How could I iterate through the 2D list, given the range of co-ordinates and change their values?

Example: Co-ordinates from position (0,0) to (0,3)

[image]

In this instance: `m[0][0], m[0][1], m[0][2] and m[0][3]` need to be changed.

Example 2: Co-ordinates (2,2) to (2,4)

[image]

In this instance: `m[2][2], m[2][3] and m[2][4]` need to be changed.

Comment: It's a 2D list, just provide i,j indexes through two loops..

Comment: Yes true. But how do I find all the locations by knowing only the co-ordinates?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that...can you explain more...

Comment: @MiKz added a snippet to mutate a slice of the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others have said it's just a list of lists

So you can index it with `m[i][j]`

But you want a range on the internal list, so you can slice it with `m[i][j:k]`

```
>>> m = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> m[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> m[0][0:4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To mutate your list, just do

```
>>> m[0][0:4] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> m
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

### Your second example

> In this instance: m[2][2], m[2][3] and m[2][4] need to be changed.

This is on different than the first example above, because it spans a single row

```
m[2][2:5] = [1,1,1]
```

### For more advanced matrix/array manipulation try numpy

If the range spans more than 1 row, I suggest you use the `numpy` library, because it's got easy flattening

```
>>> m = np.zeros(shape=(5,5))
>>> m
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> f = m.flatten()
>>> f
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> f[4:7]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> f[4:7] = [1, 1, 1]
>>> f
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> f.shape = 5,5
>>> f
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. If there was only one co-ordinate example 1,0 - I can change the value at that position by m[row][col]=new_value. But my problem is what if I had to change all the values from 1,0 to 2,2?

Comment: @MiKz Hi, for your second imgur screenshot, the first case will work, because it touches a single row. For operations spanning multiple rows I would look into flattening the matrix into a 1-dimension list first, and only bring it to matrix when I need it. Also try using `numpy` it will save you A LOT of time doing these kind of operations